# Image ng-Src with dependancy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an image on my page like so:

```
<img ng-src='http://someurl.com/image.png?parameter={{selected.id}}' />
```

Is there any way in Angular to prevent ng-src resolution until after {{selected.id}} is set?  Basically i do not want to load image until selected.id is set.  To set selected.id I need to make Ajax call.  What I am experiencing is two calls for the image.

- First one with url like so http://someurl.com/image.png?parameter=
- Then the second (correct) call after selected.id is set

It seems that this should be easy to do but I cannot think of a way.

Thank You,
Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) so the `img` tag will actually be removed until `selected.id` is truthy. This means the request for the image won't be made until `selected.id` is set.

```
<img ng-src='http://someurl.com/image.png?parameter={{selected.id}}' ng-if="selected.id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show directive

```
<img ng-src='http://someurl.com/image.png?parameter={{selected.id}}'
     ng-if="selected.id" />
```

You can find some demo here :http://jsbin.com/fatote/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Using `ng-show` does not work. There is a request for the image being made in your demo before the id is set.